# Excel Macro Buttons Text offcenter until resizing view

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-365

I have the weirdest thing going on with a file at work. We have this "Engineering Dashboard" file on the network drive at work. As far as I know, this happens to everyone on the team. The file is saved by default in a read-only state, but even if I save it corrected, it returns to the previous, broken state.

Essentially, when we open the Dashboard file, we have a number of buttons that run various macros. The issue that occurs is that the text on the buttons is not centered... until the zoom view is resized. then it recenters and stays centered no matter what size it's zoomed to. The screenshots attached are both at 100% zoom, but one is before and one is after I changed the zoom to like 110% and back to 100%.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: ActiveX-Buttons placed on a Sheet, I assume? Had similar issues a long time ago. Since then, I no longer use buttons placed on a sheet, instead, I use regular rect shapes, give them a little shadow and use color and font similar to a button. You can assign a Macro to them (right click, "Assign Macro"). Good enough for most cases and no longer issues with formatting. If you want to go fancy, you can use pictures instead of a shape, or place an image above the shape as Icon (assign the same macro also to the image)

Comment: As for an in-between fix, you could try changing the zoom levels at the `Workbook_Open` event, see [vba-code-to-control-excels-zoom-settings](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-to-control-excels-zoom-settings/) for a few examples.

Comment: @FunThomas how do I tell if it's an ActiveX-Button? I didn't create this sheet/macro. There are "regular" buttons (Form controls) and ActiveX buttons you can add under the Developer tab in the Controls section.

Comment: On the developer Tab, enable the "Design Mode". Click on the button: If it's an ActiveX control, you see something like `=EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1";"")` in the Excel input field. Form controls doesn't show anything.

Comment: I replaced all the buttons with "Form controls" and it still does it.